# Reverse proxy between two (or more) Google App Engine projects

Tags: google-app-engine, reverse-proxy, legacy

You have a Google Cloud project `Project1` with App Engine enabled and serving your legacy application.

You want to rebuild your application using a different programming language and hence need a separate project (`Project2`) with its own separate App Engine.

You want to install some kind of reverse proxy appliance in front of your `Project1` App Engine, so that you can gradually route more and more traffic to `Project2`'s App Engine.

What's the best way to achieve this?

Google Cloud Load Balancer doesn't appear to work with App Engine (only Google Compute Engine), so I'm thinking establishing a reverse proxy server (e.g. NginX) container would be the best bet.

Comment: cant you use the trafficsplit that is build in app engine? I'm just not sure if you can manage 2 different runtimes within 1 App Engine project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on how you want to organize, you can duplicate your entire application within the same project by just deploying as a different service or as new versions of your existing service. For example, say you have two services `frontend` and `backend` for a simple web app. (Let's say they're both written in Python)

For deploying as a separate service, you can create a new version of your application in a different language, say Node.js. You can deploy the new services as `frontend-node` and `backend-node`.

If you don't want to do that, you can rewrite your application in a different language and then deploy as a new version of your existing services. In the "Versions" section, you can see your versions of the same service and they can be different language runtimes.

Either way, you can then use the "split-traffic" feature to customize and test implementations of your application.

Generally speaking, you should avoid using projects to isolate different variants and/or components of your application unless you really need too. App Engine services can each be a different runtime from each other so there's almost no point in provisioning a whole new project even though you're redeploying in a different language.